# Radio button data retrieval from Firebase database to Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve user name into the profile activity and I have categorised the user according to their gender. Please, advice me how to retrieve the user name from the radio button child from *Firebase* database.
Below is my code snippet.

```
mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
int selectId = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectId);

if (radioButton.getText() == null) {
    return;
}
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(radioButton.getText().toString()).child(current_uid);
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score -3):

You can you this -

```
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
.child(radioButton.getText().toString()).child(current_uid)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        // The rest code after retrieval of a user goes here

    }
```